Producers Consumers pattern in Python using multiprocessing.Queue
I'm new to Python and its approach to concurrency. I'm trying to implement the producers consumers pattern using the multiprocessing.Queue class.
By using the Queue class can I just write the following code to implement the pattern or should I explicitly use a Lock object and two Condition variables for producers and consumers (like it's usually done in C ) ?
This is my code:
class ServerImpl(ServerSkeleton):
    def __init__(self, port, queue):
        super().__init__(port, queue)
        
    def deposita(self, item):
        self.queue.put(item)
        return "Deposited"
        
    def preleva(self):
        item = self.queue.get()
        return item

Since multiprocessing.Queue is already designed to be process-safe, I think that it should handle the necessary locking internally to ensure that data is safely exchanged between processes.

Queues are thread safe.

multiprocessing.Queue has all the needed functionality, you don't need to add any synchronization on top (nor should you).

get is blocking by default, but it doesn't have a condition variable, because it relies on the OS waking up threads when the read is done, as if you are reading from a socket or stdin, and it has a multiprocessing read lock to make concurrent reads safe.
put is not blocking because it has an internal thread to push the data through the pipe, and it has a write lock so you can put from multiple processes.

same is true for the multithreading queue.Queue. it is protected by the GIL, and has the built-in condition variable so you don't have to write any synchronization on top.
